# Valid PHP bespoke _POST?

Tags: php

I'm just writing a PHP script to deal with PayPal IPN data. I want to check how many items have been purchased, then dynamically call `$_POST['item_name1']` for each item. So it would be:

```
$_POST['item_name1']
$_POST['item_name2']
$_POST['item_name3']
etc
```

Is this a valid in PHP, I'm not getting what I expect and now sure how to test this on its own:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_items; $i++) {
    $items[$i] = $_POST[' . "item_name" . $i . '];
}
```

TIA

Comment: Might be a good idea to go back to the documentation and learn how operators work in general. This piece of code shows lack of understanding of fundamental syntax.

Comment: @mario: This POST is made automatically by the PayPal web service, not from a HTML form. The field names are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. You want:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_items; $i++) {
    $items[$i] = $_POST['item_name' . $i];
}
```

You could also use:

```
$_POST["item_name{$i}"];
```

Comment: Thanks for this considerate kind reply, I always get a bit confused when I come back to PHP! Its working now. :)